# Confusion about dendrogram

Tags: clustering

Consider the following dendrogram in aglomerative clustering :

[image]

The distance of merging the cluster containing the points p1 , p2 and p3 with the cluster containing the points p4, p5 and p6 is this distance labeled as red line :

[image]

Or it is the verticle distance from the merging horizontal line until the x-axis?  like this :

[image]